# Kotlin - How to get access to variable from callback?

Tags: android, kotlin

I trying to get access to the variable from the callback.

```
var dialog = showDialog(View.OnClickListener { dialog.dismiss() })
```

But dialog is shown as error with message 'Unresolved reference: dialog'

This is whole code fow showing full picture:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        buttonOne.setOnClickListener {
            showDialog(View.OnClickListener { Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Button one clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show() })
        }

        buttonTwo.setOnClickListener {
            var dialog = showDialog(View.OnClickListener { dialog.dismiss() })
        }

    }

    private fun showDialog(clickListener: View.OnClickListener): Dialog {
        val alertDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this@MainActivity).create()
        alertDialog.setTitle("This is title")
        alertDialog.setMessage("This is message")
        alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK") { _, _ -> clickListener.onClick(null) }
        alertDialog.show()
        return alertDialog
    }

}
```

Yes I can call to dismiss dialog

```
alertDialog.dismiss()
```

inside showDialog method. But click behaviour can be different in different cases.

So my question: how to get access to the variable from callback?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var dialog: Dialog

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        buttonOne.setOnClickListener {
            showDialog(View.OnClickListener { Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Button one clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show() })
        }

        buttonTwo.setOnClickListener {
            dialog = showDialog(View.OnClickListener { dialog.dismiss() })
        }

    }

    private fun showDialog(clickListener: View.OnClickListener): Dialog {
        val alertDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this@MainActivity).create()
        alertDialog.setTitle("This is title")
        alertDialog.setMessage("This is message")
        alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK") { _, _ -> clickListener.onClick(null) }
        alertDialog.show()
        return alertDialog
    }

}
```

Now you can access `dialog` everywhere in `MainActivity`

Answer (score 0):

Using [Anko](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko) and Kotlin's syntax it is possible to make the code more simpler and compact:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        buttonOne.setOnClickListener { showDialog { toast("Button one clicked") } }
        buttonTwo.setOnClickListener { showDialog { it.dismiss() } }
    }

    private fun showDialog(func: (DialogInterface) -> Unit) =
        alert(Appcompat, "This is message") {
            title = "This is title"
            okButton { func(it) }
        }.show()
}
```